# Exit statements won't exit all processes

Tags: c++, shell, process, fork

I'm currently running a mini shell with a C++ program, and when the user types "exit", the `main_func()` returns `-1`. At that point, the print statement (in the child process) will print, which is followed by `exit`, yet the loop (in the parent process) continues to run. Only time it'll actually end is if I use the `kill` shell command, but this does not end my program cleanly.

Kill function that would end my program

```
kill(0, SIGINT);  // send an INT signal
kill(0, SIGKILL);
```

Below is the code that won't properly exit and is stuck on the mini shell. So what exactly am I doing wrong? Is it the way the processes are created?

```
pid_t pid_new;
int status2;


int main_func()
{
    // Assume the problematic case: return -1.
    return -1;
}


int main()
{
    while(1){
        if ((pid_new = fork()) == 0){
            if(main_func() == -1){
                cout << "Ending the MiniShell...\n";
                exit(0);    // <--- The exit command
            } else {
                main_func();
            }
        }
        else if ((pid_new < 0)){
            // Error handling
        }
        else
            waitpid(pid_new, &status2,0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which `exit` are you concerned with? What exactly do you expect the this `exit` to do?

Comment: exit the main program @JaMiT

Comment: Which `exit` are you concerned with? There are two in your code snippet. (One is run by the main program of the child process when `main_func()` returns `-1`, and one is run by the main program of the parent process when `fork()` returns a negative value. Which one are you asking about?)

Comment: I'm concerned about the one when main_func() returns a -1 :) @JaMiT. My actual code is far more complex in main_func() but i dont think i could post all of it. It's just a mini shell that should continue to run until the user hits "quit"

Comment: Right, please do *not* post your entire code. All that is relevant is that the function can return `-1`. The code should be a [mre], not a mini-shell.

Comment: OK, so you are concerned about the `exit` statement run by the child process. Yet your symptom (the loop running) occurs in the parent process.

Comment: Yessir, is there something I may be doing wrong? @JaMiT also i truly appreciate your help. thank you

Comment: There is no `exit` after `waitpid`, due to `while (1)` the process will just repeat.

Comment: if do put an exit after waitpid, the program will only run one command in the mini shell before returning to the normal shell . And it's supposed to continously run until the user types quit. @rustyx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, `fork()` creates a separate process (child). Most of the actions taken in the child process are not reflected in the parent. `exit()` is one such action. After calling `exit()`, the child is terminated, and the parent remains unaffected (well, SIGCHLD is passed to the parent who is mostly ignored).

So to notify the parent of the `exit()` event (`main_func()` returning -1), you need to adopt some extra mechanism. One way to do this is, signaling the parent. But to signal the parent, parent PID is required. Unlike in the case of the parent, `fork()` won't return the parent PID in the child. You need to call `getppid()` for obtaining the parent PID. Following code does the same:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

pid_t pid_new;
int status2;


int main_func()
{
    // Assume the problematic case: return -1.
    return -1;
}


int main()
{
    while(1){
        if ((pid_new = fork()) == 0){
            if(main_func() == -1){
                cout << "Ending the MiniShell...\n";
                kill(getppid(), SIGINT);   // Interrupt the parent
                exit(0);    // <--- The exit command
            } else {
                main_func();
            }
        }
        else if ((pid_new < 0)){
            // Error handling
        }
        else
            waitpid(pid_new, &status2,0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal Session:

```
$ gcc SO.c 
$ ./a.out 
Ending the MiniShell...

$
```

**Regarding which signal to be passed:** Any signal whose default disposition is termination. Since you did not show your full code, I assume no signal handler is installed for `SIGINT`. Alternatively, if you wish to do some cleanup instead of immediate termination, you can register a signal handler for the same.